# How to use torch.nn.DataParallel if I have more than one network working in tandem?

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu, dataparallel

I have a model as such:

```
netF = timm.create_model(...) #feature extractor
netB = network.feat_bottlenect(...) #bottleneck layer
netC = network.feat_classifier(...) #classifier layer
output = netF(netB(netC(input)))
```

I want to apply torch.nn.DataParallel to these networks. I tried applying DataParallel to each individual network, as follows.

```
netF = torch.nn.DataParallel(netF)
netB = torch.nn.DataParallel(netB)
netC = torch.nn.DataParallel(netC)
output = netF(netB(netC(input)))
```

but it does not seem to work. This is the only change I made to go from single GPU to miltiple GPUs.
The overall model trains fine on a single GPU without DataParallel.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

I am expecting the model to train as it would without DataParallel.